# Can imports with question marks be handled in Jest?

Tags: svg, import, jestjs, svgr

In a JS/Webpack/Jest project, I am attempting to import SVG files using the syntax:

```
import imageUrl from './image.svg?url
```

(This style is [recommended by SVGR in their documentation](https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/#use-svgr-and-asset-svg-in-the-same-project).)

However, when I attempt to run tests, I hit an issue with Jest:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module './image.svg?url' from 'src/components/Home/Home.jsx'

    Require stack:
      src/components/Home/Home.jsx
      src/components/App.jsx
      src/components/App.test.jsx

      3 | import ErrorBoundary from '../ErrorBoundary';
      4 | import Loading from '../Loading';
    > 5 | import imageUrl from './image.svg?url'
```

I have attempted to configure `jest.config.ts` to support these imports, e.g. with:

```
 transform: {
    '.+\\.(css|css!|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2|svg\\?url)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
```

But this has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with Jest config along the lines of:

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(.+\\.svg)(\\?\\w+)$': '$1',
```

This issue is discussed in https://github.com/pd4d10/vite-plugin-svgr/issues/97